# MVC3 gives a Blank chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts

My LoggedUserHome.Controller has this action for chart

```
 public ActionResult GetGender()
    {


        var AllGender = new List<string>(from c in db.tbl_Profile select c.sex).ToList();
        var Groping = AllGender
           .GroupBy(i => i)
           .Select(i => new { sex = i.Key, CountGet = i.Count() }).ToArray(); //get a count for each

        var key = new Chart(width: 300, height: 300)
            .AddSeries(
            chartType: "pie",
            legend: "Gender Popularity",
            xValue: Groping, xField: "sex",
            yValues: Groping, yFields: "CountGet")
            .Write("gif");
        return null;

    }
```

and in my view I have given

```
<img src="/LoggedUserHome/GetGender"/>
```

Thanks to Nexuss ToArray() suggestion I manage to populate the chart by reading the database.. Thanks a lot Nexuzz

Comment: Your action doesn't return any data, but null, so the chart won't appear on your UI.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is to try to replace your

```
<img src="/LoggedUserHome/GetGender"/>
```

in the view with

```
@{
    var d = new PrimeTrekkerEntities1();
    var AllGender = new List<string>(from c in d.tbl_Profile select c.sex).ToList();
    var Groping = AllGender
        .GroupBy(i => i)
        .Select(i => new { sex = i.Key, Count = i.Count() }); //get a count for each

    var key = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddSeries(
        chartType: "pie",
        legend: "Gender Popularity",
        xValue: Groping, xField: "sex")
        .Write("gif");
}
```

And "yes" you don't need action GetGender in this case.

More complex solution would be to leave

```
<img src="/LoggedUserHome/GetGender"/>
```

in the view, but make GetGender() action return chart image URL. So, what you can do in GetGender() is somehow render chart into image file and return response that contains the image's path.

**update:**

I've updated your example a bit, so it displays data in the chart. Here is what I've got:

```
@{
    var AllGender = new List<string>() { "Male", "Female", "Male"};
    var Groping = AllGender
        .GroupBy(i => i)
        .Select(i => new { sex = i.Key, Count = i.Count() }).ToArray(); //get a count for each

    var key = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddSeries(
        chartType: "pie",
        legend: "Gender Popularity",
        xValue: Groping, xField: "sex",
        yValues: Groping, yFields: "count")
        .Write("gif");
}
```

There are two main differences with your example:

- `Groping` is now an array. As far as I understand Chart expects data to be enumerated
- I added `yValues` and `yFields` parameters, so chart knows what values to use on Y axis

Comment: Well thank you very much for the help nexuzzz.. but still i'm stuck with this.. If you can suggest me a very simple article which runs a query to get data from the database and then show it in the chart....

Comment: sorry - I didn't notice your comment. If it's still actual check out that article: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart Looks like it have all you need. If it's not, we can try to do something particular:)

Comment: I'hv tried this tutorial many a times.. but this is a bit older version tutorial and also it is for "Displaying Data in a Chart with ASP.NET Web Pages " not MVC... By the way Thanks for the Help

Comment: It doesn't matter. All the examples on the link are done using Razor syntax. Please check out my updated answer - I added an example that's close to your issue.

Comment: Yes this time it worked... It needed to be changed a bit.. and I managed to get wt i want.. Thanks a lot Nexuzzz thanks a lot